# Try-catch no maneja la excepción del throw de un future

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo la siguiente función asíncrona que tiene un timeout por si la petición dura más de 5 segundos:

```
  Future<List<Product>> initProducts() async {
        if(!productsHaveBeenInitialized){
          try{
            products = await ProductDatabaseService.readProducts().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5)); 
            productsHaveBeenInitialized = true;
            notifyListeners();
          }on TimeoutException{
            rethrow;
          } catch (e){
            rethrow;
          }
        }
        return products;
  }
```

Y aqui es donde la llamo:

```
 try{
    productProvider.initProducts();
  }on ClientIsOfflineException{
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('offline');
  }on TimeoutException{
    NotificationsService.showSnackbar("Por favor, revise su conexión");
  }catch(e){
    NotificationsService.showSnackbar("Ha ocurrido un error al leer los productos");
  }
```

El caso es que cuando hago el test de probarlo sin conexión a internet, debería mostrar un `SnackBar` diciendo "Por favor, revise su conexión" ya que se terminaría el tiempo del timeout y el `rethrow` lanzaría la excepción que manejaría el segundo try.

Sin embargo, la aplicación se detiene como si el `rethrow` fuera una excepción sin manejar cuando sí lo es. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Esta es una imagen de como el editor de texto muestra el error:
[image: Error]

En cambio, si manejo la excepción en la misma función si maneja el error correctamente:

```
  Future<List<Product>> initProducts() async {
    if(!productsHaveBeenInitialized){
        try{
            products = await ProductDatabaseService.readProducts().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5)); 
            productsHaveBeenInitialized = true;
            notifyListeners();
        }on TimeoutException{
          NotificationsService.showSnackbar("Error en la conexión");
        } catch (e){
            rethrow;
        }
    }
        return products;
  }
```

Comment: porque ya estás capturando la excepción en el Future -> productProvider.initProducts().onError(  <---

Comment: Cuando una función es asíncrona, como en el caso de initProducts, creo que debes hacer un await desde donde lo invoques, sino, no podrás capturar el error. Además, como comenta diego, ya estás capturando el error con el .onError

Comment: el .onError no cambia en nada al problema. No importa si lo dejo o lo quito que le problema es el mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como me indicaron en los comentarios, el problema estaba en que si no utilizo un `await` el try no entra en el catch. Para resolverlo he extraído la llamada a una función asincrona:

```
Future<void> _initProducts(BuildContext context) async {
  ProductProvider productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
  try{
    await productProvider.initProducts();
  }on TimeoutException{
    InternetService.showInternetAlertDialog(context);
  }catch(e){
    NotificationsService.showSnackbar("Error al leer los productos");
  }
}
```